# Android studio firebase how to download and show image(without uploading first!)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have an script which works perfectly regarding uploading an image, and then showing it on my app. Here is my full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private StorageReference mStorageRef;

Button btnPickImage, btnUpload, buttonDownload;

ImageView imgSource, imgDestination;

LinearLayout lv;

Uri selectedImage;

ProgressBar pbbar;

DatabaseReference databaseReference, childReference;

private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_PHOTO = 2;

StorageReference fireRef;


private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

FirebaseUser currentUser;

String imageURL = "";




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    pbbar = findViewById(R.id.pbbar);
    pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    lv = findViewById(R.id.lv);
    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    btnPickImage = findViewById(R.id.btnPickImage);
    btnUpload = findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
    buttonDownload = findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);
    buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //justDownloadWithoutUploading();
        }
    });

    imgSource = findViewById(R.id.imgSource);
    imgDestination = findViewById(R.id.img);
    btnPickImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                    Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)
                    && !Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                    Environment.MEDIA_CHECKING)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_PHOTO);

            } else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No gallery found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            UploadImages();
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_PHOTO) {
            Bitmap originBitmap = null;
            selectedImage = data.getData();
            InputStream imageStream;
            try {
                pbbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                        selectedImage);
                originBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (originBitmap != null) {
                {
                    this.imgSource.setImageBitmap(originBitmap);
                    pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imgSource.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            } else
                selectedImage = null;
        }

    }
}

public String GetDate() {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    String currentdate = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    return currentdate;
}

public void UploadImages() {
    try {
        pbbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        String strFileName = GetDate() + "img.jpg";

        Uri file = selectedImage;

        fireRef = mStorageRef.child("images/" + currentUser.getUid().toString() + "/" + strFileName);

        UploadTask uploadTask = fireRef.putFile(file);


        Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw task.getException();
                }


                //return fireRef.getDownloadUrl();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Calling method!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return downloadImage(fireRef);


            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    Log.e("Image URL", downloadUri.toString());

                    pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    selectedImage = null;
                    imageURL = downloadUri.toString();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image upload unsuccessful. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                DownloadImageFromURL downloadImageFromURL = new DownloadImageFromURL();
                downloadImageFromURL.execute("");
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private class DownloadImageFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            Log.e("imageURL is ", imageURL);
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
            if (in != null) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } else
                Log.e("Empty InputStream", "InputStream is empty.");
        } catch (MalformedInputException e) {
            Log.e("Error URL", e.getMessage().toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Input stream error", "Input stream error");
        }
        return "";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            imgDestination.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else
            Log.e("Empty Bitmap", "Bitmap is empty.");
    }
}




public Task<Uri> downloadImage(StorageReference fireRef){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "THIS METHOD GOT CALLED.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return fireRef.getDownloadUrl();

}}
```

However, I have added an extra button to just download a picture (no uploading!), but I am struggling to make this possible. I have made a method for this called "justDownloadWithoutUploading"

code:

```
    public void justDownloadWithoutUploading(){
    final StorageReference img_dest;
    img_dest = mStorageRef.child("images/" + currentUser.getUid().toString() + "/" + "20200203144042img.jpg");

    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    final StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
    final StorageReference islandRef = storageRef.child("images/20200203144042img.jpg"); //gs://viproverselvfølgeligigjen.appspot.com/images/20200203144042img.jpg

    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
    islandRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
            // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returns, use this as needed
            downloadImage(img_dest);   // ERROR: 2020-02-04 14:48:29.272 27487-27830/com.example.admin_panel E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred?

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
        }
    });


}
```

This method will create the references into the specific image, and then call the "public Task downloadImage" at the end adding the link into the parameter, but nothing happens..

Full error:

```
    2020-02-04 17:31:06.669 1020-1456/com.example.admin_panel E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
2020-02-04 17:31:06.671 1020-1456/com.example.admin_panel E/StorageException: Could not open resulting stream.
    java.io.IOException: Could not open resulting stream.
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.createDownloadStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:143)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.access$000(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:38)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$1.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:165)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$1.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:162)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$StreamProgressWrapper.ensureStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:324)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$StreamProgressWrapper.access$100(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:261)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:173)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:1106)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Could someone here plz help me?

Comment: Please find the complete error message and stack trace in the logcat output of your app, and add it to your question.

Comment: Question is now edited and i added full stack trace.

Comment: The best way to show image is Glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide recommended by google

Comment: This message `Object does not exist at location.` seems to indicate that the path on the server doesn't exist.

Comment: Of course it exist.. I have written the adress correctly